# I am trying to add linear gradient color to my svg stroke attribute within lwc but it is not working. Can anyone help with finding the problem?

Tags: lwc-oss, svg

**in html i have this svg code.**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100px" height="100px">
                <defs>
                   <linearGradient id="gradientcolor">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                   </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="42" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </svg>
```

**and in css i have :**

```
circle {
fill:none;
stroke=url(#gradientcolor);
stroke-width: 15px;
stroke-dasharray: 260;
stroke-dashoffset: 100;
```

}

it is working for solid color, for example **stroke="red"** but when i am trying to refer the id within the url it is not working.

Salesforce document says they support "**defs**" tag. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably already noticed it, looking at the rendered HTML: The `id` of the `linearGradient` is not the one ("gradientcolor") you assigned anymore...

From what I can tell, [there is no way to refer to `defs` without `id`'s](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#URLandURI). There are two solutions:

**1. Figure out the `id` the `linearGradient` in Javascript and assign the `url` dynamically**

HTML, with small additions:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100px" height="100px">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient lwc:ref="gradientcolor" id="gradientcolor">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle lwc:ref="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="42" stroke-linecap="round"/>
</svg>
```

The Javascript:

```javascript
_rendered = false;

renderedCallback() {
    if (this._rendered) {
        return;
    }
    this._rendered = true;

    const id = this.refs.gradientcolor.id;
    this.refs.circle.setAttribute('stroke', 'url(#' + id + ')');
}
```

In this case, the `stroke` attribute got removed from the CSS:

```css
circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 15px;
    stroke-dasharray: 260;
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
}
```

**2. Upload the SVG as a static resource and use it like an image**

Move all the (CSS) SVG specs into the file that is uploaded as static resource (as HTML attributes):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100px" height="100px">
    <defs>
       <linearGradient id="gradientcolor">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
       </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="42" stroke-linecap="round" 
        stroke="url(#gradientcolor)" 
        fill="none" 
        stroke-width="15px" 
        stroke-dasharray="260" 
        stroke-dashoffset="100"/>
</svg>
```

The markup of the LWC will then have:

```html
<template>
    <img src={svgUrl}/>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```javascript
import my_svg from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/nameOfStaticResource";
[...]
svgUrl = my_svg;
```

Comment: Thank you @Felix. Usually i work with classes so I totally forgot id is attached with additional values when it is rendered within the browser. :')

Comment: @SutanuDebnath, yes, it's easy to forget! And I'm not even sure I understand why `id`s need to be unique across LWC's Shadow DOM boundaries.